# The term 'flutter' is not recognized on window

Tags: flutter, build, apk, config, release

I was run command `flutter build apk` then I got error :
[This is image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idxao.png)

```dart
flutter: The term 'flutter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ flutter build apk
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (flutter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException    
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

This is my config for flutter
[This is image config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJbzM.png)
And location flutter on my computer
[This is image location flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPEGj.png)

Thank you for supporting

Comment: You can click on description image to see image detail issues

Comment: Add `<flutter>\bin` to your system path, and then reopen your terminal to type in the command.

Comment: oh i added <flutter>\bin in my system path. It's like c\flutter\flutter\bin. U can see that image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJbzM.png in my post. I make sure it is correct. So any solutions other.
Thank you for supporting

Answer (score 0):

You have to [add Flutter to path](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path):

- From the Start search bar, enter ‘env’ and select Edit environment variables for your account.
- Under User variables check if there is an entry called Path:

  - If the entry exists, append the full path to flutter\bin using ; as a
    separator from existing values.
  - If the entry doesn’t exist, create a new user variable named Path with the full path to flutter\bin as its value.

You have to close and reopen any existing console windows for these changes to take effect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: oh i added <flutter>\bin in my system path. It's like c\flutter\flutter\bin. U can see that image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJbzM.png in my post. I make sure it is correct. So any solutions other.
Thank you for supporting